# Kotlin OnItemClickListener for a RecyclerView inside a Fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

The problem is related to the fact  that I don't manage to implement a OnItemClick listener for a RecyclerView that is located in a "mainFragment" by implementing the OnClickListener in the Adapter.

I would like my application (kotlin) to launch another fragment ("deletePage" in the code bellow) everytime an itemView (an ImageView) from the RecyclerView is clicked, this fragment would display the same photo in big.

My Adapter code is the following one:

```
 class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var photo = emptyList<Photo>()
    
    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return photo.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.longitude.text = photo[position].latitude
        holder.itemView.latitude.text = photo[position].longitude
        holder.itemView.imageView.load(photo[position].photo)
    }

    fun setData(photo: List<Photo>) {
        this.photo = photo
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

And my mainFragment code is the following one:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(){

    private lateinit var myView: MyViewModel
    private val adapter by lazy { MyAdapter() }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)

        //Recyclerview
        val adapter = MyAdapter()
        val recyclerView = view.recycler_view
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        myView = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        myView.readPhoto.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {photo ->
            adapter.setData(photo)
        })

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_database, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when {
            item.itemId == R.id.deleteAll -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.deletePage)
            item.itemId == R.id.refresh -> {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "yep", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                instertDataToDatabase()
            }
        }
        if (item.itemId == R.id.deleteAll) {
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

The objective is that when you click on an item of the RecyclerView the "findNavController().navigate(R.id.deletePage)" fragment is displayed but everytime I try to implement a solution the application crashes when clicking at an item of the RecyclerView. Right now the navigation works by the click on a button in the Menu at the toolbar but is not the ideal solution.

Any sort of help or advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to give click listener of your itemView in `onBindViewHolder`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.longitude.text = photo[position].latitude
    holder.itemView.latitude.text = photo[position].longitude
    holder.itemView.imageView.load(photo[position].photo)
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { navigateToFragment() }
}
```

For the navigation somehow you should have a context instance.
Here is the possible solutions that came up to my mind:

> 1. Give navigator instance to adapter

```
class Navigator(fragment: Fragment) {
    private val fragmentRef = WeakReference(fragment)

    fun navigate(){
        // make your navigations here with using fragmentRef.get()
    }
}
```

In your fragment:

```
private val navigator = Navigator(this)
         ...
val adapter = MyAdapter(navigator)
```

In your adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(private val navigator: Navigator) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

fun navigateToFragment(){
   navigator.navigate()
}
```

> 2. Make interface for callback
>
> 2.1. Implement that interface in fragment and give adapter the interface instance

```
interface Navigable{
   fun navigate()
}
```

In your fragment:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(), Navigable{
      ...

override fun navigate(){
    // make your navigation
}

val adapter = MyAdapter(navigator)
```

In your adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(private val navigable: Navigable) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

fun navigateToFragment(){
   navigable.navigate()
}
```

> 2.2. Make the interface, but do not pass reference, use findFragment in adapter

In your adapter: override `onAttachedToRecyclerView` to find fragment

```
private lateinit var navigable: Navigable

override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    navigable = recyclerView.findFragment<Fragment>() as Navigable
}

fun navigateToFragment(){
   navigable.navigate()
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the adapter should implement the on click logic or keep a reference to the host fragment. Instead, I think exposing a callback and using it to implement the fragment's action would be a better solution.

Comment: I prefer using databinding and giving click listener from xml, however in this example, view only reachable inside the adapter. Either we will pass view from adapter to fragment or adapter will notify the fragment with callback. How would you make callback from adapter without reference?